# Problem with LTSP mount NFS

Tags: server, ltsp-client

I have a problem with mounting nfs drive to my thin client. Already mount and fstab manually on chroot image but when boot up, my thin client didn't see anuthing on fstab.

Triend on LTSP.conf, the result still same.

What went wrong?